# Laravel model relationship producing wrong sql when I delete a model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building an app that has users and user roles.  A user can have many roles.

I have 3 tables setup:

- user
- role
- role_user

In my `user` model I have this:

```
...

/**
 * Boot the model.
 *
 */
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($user)
    {
        $user->roles()->delete();
    });
}

/**
 * The roles that belong to the user.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('SimplyTimesheets\Models\User\Role')->withTimestamps();
}

...
```

When I delete a user, I want it to delete the associated row(s) from `role_user` table also.

My delete method looks like this:

```
/**
 * Delete user.
 *
 * @param $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function deleteUser($id)
{
    return $this->user->whereId($id)->delete();
}
```

However, this results in the following SQL being generated:

```
delete `role` from `role` inner join `role_user` on `role`.`id` = `role_user`.`role_id` where `role`.`cust_id` = ? and `role_user`.`user_id` = ?
```

Why is it trying to delete the row from `role` table and not from `role_user`?

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`detach`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models) method, not the `delete` method:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($user)
    {
        $user->roles()->detach();
    });
}
```